# What is the difference between `std::default_initializable` and `std::is_default_constructible`?

Tags: c++, c++20

C++20 adds a concept called [`std::default_initializable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/default_initializable). The difference in naming compared to [`std::is_default_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible) seems to be way too obvious to be accidental.

Their specifications are worded differently as well (at least on cppreference), however I don't understand what the **effective** differences are.

Here's a short summary of the cppreference articles:

`std::is_default_constructible<T>` requires `T foo();` to be well-formed, with the assumption that it's not parsed as a function declaration. In other words (if I understand correctly), <s>`T` needs to be destructible and</s> `T()` needs to be well-formed.
<sub>(edit: it doesn't seem to require destructibility, so here's the first difference)</sub>

`std::default_initializable`, on the other hand, requires both `T foo;`, `T()` and `T{}` to be well-formed.

Are there any effective differences between those two?

As far as I know, `T{}` is always interpreted as `T()` (ignoring most vexing parse, which doesn't count here), so I'm not sure why it's mentioned explicitly. Also `T()` being well-formed seems to imply `T foo;` being well-formed.

Comment: It seems there were some corner cases found during the concept proposal review https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#3149 - https://godbolt.org/z/I64p_E

Comment: `struct T { T(std::initializer_list <int>);}` is a case where ` T()` and `T{}` are different: the former is ill-formed and the latter is well formed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is basically [LWG 3149](https://wg21.link/LWG3149):

> `DefaultConstructible<T>` is equivalent to `Constructible<T>` (18.4.11 [concept.constructible]), which is equivalent to `is_constructible_v<T>` (20.15.4.3 [meta.unary.prop]). Per 20.15.4.3 [meta.unary.prop] paragraph 8:
>
> > The predicate condition for a template specialization `is_­constructible<T, Args...>` shall be satisfied if and only if the following variable definition would be well-formed for some invented variable t:
> >
> > ```
> > T t(declval<Args>()...);
> > ```
>
> `DefaultConstructible<T>` requires that objects of type `T` can be *value-initialized*, rather than *default-initialized* as intended.

The motivation for the concept is to check if you can write:

```
T t;
```

But the definition doesn't check that, it checks if you could write `T()`. But `T()` also doesn't mean that you can write `T{}` - there are types for which those have different meaning:

> ```
> struct S0 { explicit S0() = default; };
> struct S1 { S0 x; }; // Note: aggregate
> S1 x;   // Ok
> S1 y{}; // ill-formed; copy-list-initializes x from {}
> ```

And the intent is to simplify, for the sake of sanity, what the library has to deal with so we want to reject `S1` as just being weird.

---

And then once the concept is checking something different from `is_default_constructible`, [LWG 3338](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3338) renamed it. Since, different things should have different names.

Comment: By "copy-list-initializes", you mean - tries to use a copy ctor? I'm not sure what that word means.

Comment: Also apparently there's a more trivial difference, with `is_default_constructible` not requiring the type to be destructible.

Comment: @einpoklum Here's an explanation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: @einpoklum: No, he means "copy-list-initialization", a specific form of list initialization (aka: what you get with `T t = {...};`). Any member of an aggregate that is not given an initializer or a default initializer will be [initialized by copy-list-initialization from an empty braced-init-list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#8).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: So, even though S1 is being direct-list-initialized, S1.x gets copy-list-initialized? Shouldn't it be direct-list-initialized with `{}` itself?

Comment: @einpoklum: `y` is undergoing direct-list-initialization; `y.x`, as a subobject of `y`, has to be initialized in some way. And remember: if you provide an initializer for an aggregate member, the member will be initialized by *copy-initialization* from that initializer, regardless of whether the aggregate is being direct or copy-list-initialized. So the standard simply substitutes in `{}` for each member you didn't initialize. Hence, they get copy-initialized from `{}`, which invokes copy-list-initialization.

Comment: You can find an example for the IMO more surprising case, where `T();` works but `T t` doesn't, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75253260/758345).

Comment: @Chronial Sure, `using T = int const;` or `struct T { const int x; };`

Answer (score 3):

In short `std::default_initializable<T>` requires `std::is_default_constructible<T> && std::destructible<T>`, as well as a few corner cases of default construction.

Looking at the [spec](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/default_initializable),

```
template<class T> 
concept default_initializable = 
    std::constructible_from<T> && 
    requires { T{}; } && 
    requires { ::new (static_cast<void*>(nullptr)) T; };
```

Whereas for  `std::is_default_construtible`, the spec [defines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible)

> If `std::is_constructible<T>::value` is true, provides the member constant `value` equal to `true`, otherwise `value` is `false`.

Looking further into the definition of `default_initializable`, the spec [defines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/constructible_from)

```
template < class T, class... Args >
concept constructible_from =
    std::destructible<T> && 
    std::is_constructible<T, Args...>::value;
```

Since we are only looking at `std::constructible_from<T>` then we can then see that the definition of `default_initializable` can be rewritten as

```
template<class T> 
concept default_initializable = 
    std::is_constructible<T>::value &&
    std::destructrible<T> && 
    requires { T{}; } && 
    requires { ::new (static_cast<void*>(nullptr)) T; };
```

And finally as

```
template<class T> 
concept default_initializable = 
    std::is_default_constructible<T>::value &&
    std::destructrible<T> && 
    requires { T{}; } && 
    requires { ::new (static_cast<void*>(nullptr)) T; };
```

Comment: Good find on `std::is_default_constructible` not requiring the type to be destructible.  It seems that for the purposes of this trait, the fact that `T foo;` requires a destructor is ignored...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Traits don't define what statements or expressions are valid.

Comment: @NicolBolas `std::is_constructible` is [defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.unary.prop#8) in terms of validity of `T foo(...);`, that's what caused my confusion. But then it says that various "side effects" of this declarations (such as the destructor being required, it seems), are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

LWG issue 3338

- [3338. Rename default_constructible to default_initializable](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue3338)

highlights a difference in meaning between the `is_default_constructible` trait and the C++20 concept originally named `default_constructible`, were [LWG issue 3149](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#3149) to be accepted:

> #### 3149 DefaultConstructible should require default initialization
>
> **Discussion**
>
> [...] [the concept] `DefaultConstructible<T>` requires that objects of type `T` can be value-initialized, **rather than default-initialized as intended**.
>
> The library **needs a constraint that requires object types to be default-initializable**. [...]
>
> Users will also want a mechanism to provide such a constraint, and they're likely to choose `DefaultConstructible` **despite its subtle unsuitability**.

Tim Song provided an example as for when the requirement of "can be value-initialized" is too weak as compared to the stricter requirement of "can be default initialized".

> Tim Song noted that `{}` is not necessarily a valid initializer for a
> `DefaultConstructible` type. In this sample program (see Compiler
> Explorer):
>
> ```
> struct S0 { explicit S0() = default; };
> struct S1 { S0 x; }; // Note: aggregate
> S1 x;   // Ok
> S1 y{}; // ill-formed; copy-list-initializes x from {}
> ```
>
> `S1` can be default-initialized, **but not list-initialized from an
> empty braced-init-list**. The consensus among those present was that
> `DefaultConstructible` should prohibit this class of pathological
> types **by requiring that initialization form to be valid**.

Issue 3149 has has since been moved to status WP (essentially accepted save for as a Technical Corrigendum).

Issue 3338 has subsequently also been given WP status, renaming the `default_constructible` concept to `default_initializable`:

> #### 3338. Rename default_constructible to default_initializable
>
> **Discussion**
>
> [...] It was made clear during discussion in LEWG **that 3149 would change the concept to require default-initialization to be valid rather than value-initialization** which the `is_default_constructible` trait requires. LEWG agreed that **it would be confusing to have a trait and concept with very similar names yet slightly different meanings** [...].
>
> **Proposed resolution:**
>
> [...] Change the stable name "[concept.defaultconstructible]" to "[concept.default.init]" and retitle "Concept `default_constructible`" to "Concept `default_initializable`". Replace all references to the name `default_constructible` with `default_initializable` (There are 20 occurrences).

Comment: But what is this *"slight difference"* in meanings? There's one corner case mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/users/4074081/dewaffled , not sure if there are more. Suggest adding that to the answer.