# Do Boost Graph bundled properties need to be default constructible?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

## My objective (background)

I want to use the Boost Graph `adjacency_list` with bundled properties, but separating the user-defined properties class from the actual (and noisy) instantiation of the graph.

In the function that consumes the bundles to instantiate the `adjacency_list`, I ended up adding these constraints to the signature:

```cpp
template<class VertexProperties, class EdgeProperties>
      requires std::constructible_from<VertexProperties, std::string> &&
               std::constructible_from<EdgeProperties, double>
auto foo(...){ /* instantiate the adjacency list */}
```

But I was surprised that the constraints did not seem sufficient, as it seems the bundled properties also have to be default constructible? I don't understand why.

## What I tried

My problem boils down to the following code, that also lives on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/xehsYrd61). Desactivating the faulty constructor and activating the default constructor will make it compile and run.

```cpp
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

struct my_vertex{
  std::string name;
  //my_vertex(std::string s="default"): name{s} { std::cout << "vertex built!" << std::endl; }
  my_vertex(std::string s): name{s} { std::cout << "vertex built!" << std::endl; }
};

struct my_edge{
  double length;
  //my_edge(double d=1.0): length{d} {std::cout << "edge built!" << std::endl;}
  my_edge(double d): length{d} {std::cout << "edge built!" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    using graph_t = boost::adjacency_list<
      boost::setS,
      boost::vecS,
      boost::directedS,
      my_vertex,
      my_edge>;

    graph_t graph;
    auto u = add_vertex(my_vertex{"toto"}, graph);
    auto v = add_vertex(my_vertex{"toto"}, graph);
    add_edge(u, v, my_edge{1.0}, graph);
}
```

## My question

Obviously: "what am I doing wrong?" But it's also wrapped up with a bunch of others interrogations I have with bundled properties:

1. In the documentation, POD are used, I did not see any explicit constructors. Why?
2. Why do we have to pass an explicit `my_vertex{"toto"}`and not simply a `std::string`: I would have thought the function could forward the required parameters to the constructor of the bundled property?
3. Why does it need to be default constructible (and why the compiler detects that way too late in the internals of BGL) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do property bundles need to be default constructible?

Yes.

> 1. In the documentation, POD are used, I did not see any explicit constructors. Why?

They're not expressly POD. Types that can be aggregate-initialized aren't typically POD (that implies triviality *and* standard-layout).

> 2. Why do we have to pass an explicit my_vertex{"toto"}and not simply a std::string: I would have thought the function could forward the required parameters to the constructor of the bundled property?

In generic contexts argument types aren't always deduced. In this case you're passing `char[5]` and the constructor requires another implicit conversion. A two-step implicit conversion (`char[5]` -> `std::string` -> `my_vertex const&` is not considered by compilers).

You can of course have your cake and eat it in several ways:

```
auto    u = add_vertex({"toto"}, graph);
auto    v = add_vertex({"kansas"}, graph);
```

Or, if you must:

```
template <typename... I> my_vertex(I&&... init) : name(std::forward<I>(init)...) {
    std::cout << "vertex built!" << std::endl;
}
```

Now both work:

```
auto    u = add_vertex({"toto"}, graph);
auto    v = add_vertex("kansas", graph);
```

3. Why does it need to be default constructible (and why the compiler detects that way too late in the internals of BGL) ?

Because that's how the library is specified. If they aren't, you would have to provide factories for any algorithm that may construct vertices/edges.

In that sense, it is certainly not "way too late" for the compiler to notice: partial template instantiation means that you only need to provide what is actually used. That's a feature.

---

I'd invert the question. Why would you add the constructor? Is it just to be able to drop the `{}` around the initializers? In cases where that would make sense to me, why don't you just [use the member type as the bundle](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/271ef6949803f392)?

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

using my_vertex = std::string;
using my_edge   = double;

int main() {
    using graph_t = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                                          my_vertex, my_edge>;

    graph_t graph;
    auto    u = add_vertex("toto", graph);
    auto    v = add_vertex("kansas", graph);
    add_edge(u, v, 1.0, graph);
}
```

Or indeed, just use [aggregate initialization](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9dc4d93f2bb8681):

```
struct my_vertex { std::string name; };
struct my_edge   { double length;    };

int main() {
    using graph_t = boost::adjacency_list<boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                                          my_vertex, my_edge>;

    graph_t graph;
    auto    u = add_vertex({"toto"}, graph);
    auto    v = add_vertex({"kansas"}, graph);
    add_edge(u, v, {1.0}, graph);
}
```

*Note that the constraints for aggregate types have been loosened over the years, and you can have aggregate initialization in types with custom constructors by also `= default`-ing the default constructor.*

Comment: Wonderful thank you @sehe! 
For the question "why did you add the constructor" it is mainly because I wanted to specify constraints on the foo interface `std::constructible_from<VertexProperties, std::string>` and the constraint did not work with an aggregate type, so I added the constructor. But maybe there is a better constraint suited to that case, maybe `std::default_initializable` - I'm reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/62577956/10360134

Comment: The reason why I don't want to use the member type as the bundled property is that the exact properties of the graph are user-case dependent. So I want to enable them to use any structure as long as it can be constructed/initialized from the member type.

Comment: "constraint did not work with an aggregate type, so I added the constructor" - it should in c++20, see the feature check macros and asserts: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c36c2b890c0a508

Comment: Yes I was actually checking the same thing: the constraints compile on CE but not on local, even if I'm pretty sure I enabled C++20. I will check with your features checks!

Comment: Yup your feature checks don't pass, I suspect that CMake compiles in C++17 rather than C++20 - looks like a configuration problem and it's a new question now (rather than a confusing mystery)! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: So [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20), we can see that Parenthesized initialization of aggregate (P0960R3) is only available on gcc >= 10, Clang >= 16 and not available on Apple Clang - reason why I was unable to compile this.

Comment: I'm surprised they all deal with the concept requirements at all :) You can always use a polyfill. IIRC `boost::phoenix::construct<>` started supporting aggregate initialization some time ago.